# this weird run time exception keep coming up

Tags: kotlin

This is the runtime exception: "lateinit property name Session has not been initialized" that keeps coming up.
[image]

```
class GalasatyActivity : BaseActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityGalasatyBinding
    private val list = ArrayList<Post>()
    private lateinit var readingTypes: String
    private lateinit var student :String
    private lateinit var statue :String
    private var sessionType by Delegates.notNull<Int>()
    private lateinit var nameSession:String
    private lateinit var mSharedPreferences: SharedPreferences

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityGalasatyBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        setUpActionBar()
        setupGalasatyList()
        mSharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(Constants.PREFERENCE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        //nameSession = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tv_galsa).toString()
        readingTypes = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tv_reading_type).toString()
        student = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tv_student).toString()
        statue = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tv_statue).toString()
        sessionType = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tv_session_type).toString().toInt()
        nameSession = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tv_galsa).toString()
    }
    private fun setUpActionBar(){
        setSupportActionBar(binding.toolBarGalasaty)
        supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
        binding.toolBarGalasaty.setNavigationOnClickListener {
            doubleBackToExit()
        }
    }
    private fun setupGalasatyList(){

        hideProgressBar()

        //getGalasatDetails(name,readingTypes,student,statue,sessionType)
        DataRetrofit.instance.getSessions(nameSession,readingTypes,student,statue,sessionType).enqueue(object :Callback<Post?>{
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<Post?>, response: Response<Post?>) {
                binding.rvGalasatyList.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@GalasatyActivity,LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false)
                binding.rvGalasatyList.setHasFixedSize(true)
                val galsaAdapter = GalasatyItemListAdapter(this@GalasatyActivity, list)
                binding.rvGalasatyList.adapter = galsaAdapter
                galsaAdapter.setOnClickListener(object : GalasatyItemListAdapter.OnClickListener{
                    override fun onClick(position: Int, model: Post) {
                        startActivity(Intent(this@GalasatyActivity,GalsaActivity::class.java))
                    }
                })
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<Post?>, t: Throwable) {
                Toast.makeText(this@GalasatyActivity, t.message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }

        })
    }

    private fun getGalasatDetails(name:String, readingTypes: String, student:String, statement:String, sessionType:Int){
        if (Constants.isInternetAvailable(this)){
            val retrofit: retrofit2.Retrofit = retrofit2.Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(Constants.BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build()
            val service: DataAPI = retrofit.create(DataAPI::class.java)
            val listCall: Call<Post> = service.getSessions(name,readingTypes,student,statement,sessionType)
            showProgressDialog(resources.getString(R.string.please_wait))
            listCall.enqueue(object :Callback<Post?> {
                @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
                override fun onResponse(call: Call<Post?>, response: Response<Post?>) {
                    if (response.isSuccessful){
                        hideProgressBar()
                        val galasatList: Post? = response.body()
                        val sessionResponseJsonString = Gson().toJson(galasatList)
                        val editor = mSharedPreferences.edit()
                        editor.putString(Constants.SESSIONS_RESPONSE_DATA, sessionResponseJsonString)
                        editor.apply()
                        setupUI()
                        Log.i("Response result","$galasatList")
                    }else{
                        when(response.code()){
                            400->{
                                Log.e("Error 400","Bad connection")
                            }404->{
                            Log.e("Error 404","Not found")
                        }else->{
                            Log.e("Error","Generic error")
                        }
                        }
                    }
                }

                override fun onFailure(call: Call<Post?>, t: Throwable) {
                    hideProgressBar()
                    Log.e("erorrr", t.message.toString())
                }

            })
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(this,"No internet connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
    private fun setupUI(){
        val galasatResponseJsonString = mSharedPreferences.getString(Constants.SESSIONS_RESPONSE_DATA,"")
        if (!galasatResponseJsonString.isNullOrEmpty()) {
            val galasatList = Gson().fromJson(galasatResponseJsonString, Post::class.java)
            for (i in Post.toString()) {

                readingTypes = galasatList.readingType
                student = galasatList.student
                statue = galasatList.student
                nameSession = galasatList.name
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you converting all the views to `String`, Omar?  That's not how you initialize the views. Plus you're also using binding, then why not directly go with the binding way. Also, if you want to initialize the views, do it as `lateinit var textView: TextView` and then in the function as `textView = findViewById(R.id.textView)`. See, no `toString()`.

Comment: the problem is that I initialized the rest of them the same way but the runtime exception only appears in this var

Comment: Share the full code here, only then I can help, even the error is in line no. 64 which I can't see, neither I can see the declaration of the variable. Plus the reason for the error with this only can be because of it being used first and the code breaks at that point.

Comment: here is the full code for the activity I posted it in the question itself

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

You're initializing a view into a string which is outrightly wrong.

See, here you've declared a variable as `lateinit var nameSession: String` and then you're initializing it with a view as `nameSession = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tv_galsa).toString()` , that too as String which actually doesn't make sense.

Second, the error is about `nameSession` which as I said earlier is used first in the line no. 64 - `DataRetrofit.instance.getSessions(nameSession,...`, so the code breaks at this very point and you think that it will work with others, just not this which is again not the case because your code is wrong.

See, There are two cases, Either you want to pass the text value of the `TextView` `nameSession` and others, or the view in the `getSessions()`.

1. To passs the view, declare it as `lateinit var nameSession: TextView`, initialize it as `nameSession = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tv_galsa)` and pass it as `DataRetrofit.instance.getSessions(nameSession,...)`.
2. To pass the text value of the `TextView`, declare and initialize it exactly as my first point, just pass it as `DataRetrofit.instance.getSessions(nameSession.text,...)`.

Do the 2nd point for others as well. You **DON'T** convert the view to String, you convert the value of the view to String, and to get the value, you use the `.text` property of the `TextView` as I've used in the 2nd point.(`setText()` and `getText()` in Java).

So, convert all your variables as Views, and then pass their value using the `.text` property. One more of doing it will be `nameSession = binding.tv_galsa.text`.